# Would a gravitational wave shift where a laser pointer is pointing?

Tags: gravitational-waves

I know the effect would be incredibly small if there is one.
If I were to point a laser pointer at the moon and a gravitational wave were to pass by perpendicularly to the laser would it shift the point on the moon momentarily as the wave passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why it would. Gravitational waves are transverse.

The geometrical arrangement you describe, with a "plane" gravitational wave (a reasonable approximation for waves from a distant gravitational wave source) travelling in say the z direction, means that the laser light is directed in the transverse xy plane of the wave. That means the only observed effect can be a stretching or compression of the space along the line of the laser (or there could be no effect at all depending on the gravitational wave polarization).

To get a displacement of the laser direction towards the Moon, you need the gravitational wave to be travelling in a direction that is *not* at right angles to the laser.

Comment: I added a comment to my answer, having seen yours. I think you read the question more carefully than I did!

Comment: Suppose the laser points along x. I agree the GW component along x shouldn't change the beam's direction. But what about the component along y?

Comment: @Sten if you consider the metric for light travelling along the x-axis, don't you set $dy=0$ and so the tensor component of the perturbation in that direction has no effect?

Comment: Ah, are you thinking of a plane wave that is uniform and coherent over the distance between the earth and the moon? That's a sensible assumption for realistic gravitational waves but is perhaps worth noting anyway.

Comment: (I guess it's kind of implied by the specification of direction, since any other configuration should spread out.)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if the direction of the GW is not coming in perpendicularly then the point where the laser hits the moon would move?

Comment: @Joe for an arbitrary gravitational wave frequency, yes.

Comment: @Joe Which is what I indicated in my answer.  The laser will not be a single plane wave, but a spectrum of plane waves at differing angles.  Thus, the GW will impact its propagation transversely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the beam will shift.

A wave of long wavelength will also shift the Moon relative to the Earth. However the illuminated spot will still move relative to the Moon, except in some special case.

One can estimate these effects by imagining that the vacuum through which the laser light is travelling had a refractive index very close to 1, and the index is modified (by a tiny amount) by the gravitational wave. This is because the equation for a null geodesic on a curved spacetime is like the equation for a light ray in a medium of varying refractive index on a flat spacetime.

*Added remark*

I think ProfRob is right about the case of a plane wave travelling in the orthogonal direction, so if that is the specific case asked about then my answer above is wrong. However the above remains correct in most cases if the wave is not a plane wave (e.g. a gravitational wave with a Gaussian intensity profile or something like that).

Waves from astrophysical sources outside the solar system will be plane waves to very good approximation on the Earth-moon distance scale when they arrive here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As the wave passes through the laser beam the beam will shift.  This would be form of gravitational lensing, whereby gravitational fields bend light much like a refractive lens.

Update based on the comments of others:
While the gravitational wave may be a 'pure' plane wave to a great approximation, the laser beam will not be given a finite aperture and distance to the moon. Therefore, the laser beam will consist of a spectrum of plane waves, and the gravitational wave can only be perpendicular with only one of them.

Thus, the gravitational wave will have a non-zero transverse component for most of the angular spectrum of the laser and will modify their propagation a teeny tiny bit.

Comment: Would the moon move as well with the wave making it appear as if the laser doesn´t move?

Comment: It depends on the exact distribution of the gravitational wave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (kinda), a passing gravitational wave would indeed cause a momentary shift in the position of the laser point on the moon's surface. This effect is a consequence of the way gravitational waves distort spacetime as they pass through it.

Gravitational waves are like ripples in spacetime itself, created by accelerating masses, such as the collision of massive objects like black holes or neutron stars and when a gravitational wave passes through a region of space, it "stretches" and "squeezes" spacetime in perpendicular directions, causing a temporary expansion and contraction of space.

Now, imagine you're aiming a laser pointer at a specific point on the moon's surface. If a gravitational wave passes through the region between Earth and the moon, it will temporarily distort the spacetime along the laser's path. As a result, the distance between the Earth and the moon (along the laser's path) will briefly change due to the "stretching" and "squeezing" caused by the passing wave.

This change in distance will cause a momentary shift in the laser point on the moon's surface. However, it's important to note that the effect of a passing gravitational wave on such a system would be extraordinarily tiny. Gravitational waves are incredibly weak by the time they reach the Earth-moon system, and the shift in the laser point would be on the order of fractions of a proton's diameter or even smaller. Detecting such a minuscule effect would be an immense technical challenge and it would most likely be negligible in practical situations.